# groupby action on django queryset

Tags: django, group-by, django-queryset

I have a db table like this:

```
id|type_id | col1 | col2 | col3
0 |     1  |   2  |  b   |   c
1 |     2  |   1  |  a   |   a
2 |     2  |   2  |  a   |   c
3 |     1  |   3  |  b   |   c
```

I need to write a queryset to have:

`[{'id':1, 'count_col1': 5, 'type_id__name':balh, 'col2':b},{'id':2, 'count_col1':3, 'type_id__name': balab, 'col2':a}]`

how can I do it? it can be done by groupby in pandas, but I don't know how to do it here.

Comment: What is the model you have here? Django does not work with tables, it works with models. Usually it is better not to define queries in terms of the tables, but in terms of these models.

Comment: it is a model ofcourse, it has id, col1, col2, col3 @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: I'm not really following why id occurs multiple times here. Usually the id is a primary key?

Comment: edited, did you get it? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: I would really advice in the future to provide the (relevant parts) of the model as well. A model does not have a 1-to-1 relation to a table. Multiple models can map to the same table.

Comment: you're right, I will provide that in future, thanks @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you aim to calculate the sum of the `col1`s for each `id`. We can do that with:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Model.objects.values('type_id').annotate(
    type_name=F('type__name'),
    count_col1=Sum('col1')
).order_by('type_id')
```

This will construct a `QuerySet` of dictionaries, that will look like:

```
<QuerySet [
    {'type_id': 1, 'type_name': 'foo', 'count_col1': 5},
    {'type_id': 2, 'type_name': 'bar', 'count_col1': 3}
]>
```

or if you want to include `col2`:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

Model.objects.values('type_id', 'col2').annotate(
    type_name=F('type__name'),
    count_col1=Sum('col1')
).order_by('type_id', 'col2')
```

Comment: it solved my question, but in col2, all type_id = 1 has value of b and all type_id = 2 has value of a. how can I add it to the queryset? @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @MHB: you include it in the `.values(..)` and `.order_by(..)`. If there is a functional dependency, then it will just make one rop for a `type_id`. That being said, *if* there is a functional dependency, you likely can optimize your database, by moving it to the table to which `type_id` refers.